# Problems With Working With Columns, Changing Their Format

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a file that contains a various number of lines to the likes of this.

```
05ALBUZZI             CLAUDIA MARIA       LBZCDM64M53F205R       236.41       197.01         6.70
```

My objective is, through mostly the use of awk and sed, to:

- Remove the first two characters from the first column (so in this case, 05) and bringing them onto a column of it's own, before column one
- Delimit all columns with `;`, while keeping fields that contain spaces (for this example the name field on the second column has the name Claudia Maria) intact, and not dividing them into two columns
- And finally, get all lines with agents that get a profit of more than 1500 (profits being displayed in the last three columns, profit is the sum of the three columns)

I've been trying to firstly select those first two characters out with the use of commands such as these:

```
awk 'FS="\t" { $0 = substr($1, 3) } 1' Agenti.txt
awk 'NR>1 {print $2}' Agenti.txt
```

But I've been getting mixed results. But since it's vital to get this out of the way for the rest of the excercise, I've been finding it basically impossible to proceed from here.

Comment: Why di you midify `$0` in the first attempt? You only want to change `$1`  IIUC

Comment: @tripleee I'll be honest, I tried a bit on my own and it was complete nothing, I tried looking on here some but that was the best I could find, and I tried it out to see what effect it would have, might not be the best to include here

Comment: What’s the relationship of the last three coloumns? Print lines where their sum is at least 1500? Or any line where one of the values is larger?

Comment: @tripleee the first one, sum of the values is at least 1500

Comment: Providing just 1 sample input isn't useful to test a requirement for only printing some of the lines.

Comment: "Delimit all columns with `;`"  - do you want to replace the TAB delimiters in the input with `;` delimiters in the output? Use `OFS=";"` for that.

Comment: Going forward, please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that one of your attempts:

> `awk 'FS="\t" { $0 = substr($1, 3) } 1' Agenti.txt`

is trying to set the `FS` to a tab so I'm going to assume your input is tab-separated.

Just walking through your objectives...

> Remove the first two characters from the first column (so in this
> case, 05) and bringing them onto a column of it's own, before column
> one

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    sub(/../,"&"FS)
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk Agenti.txt
05      ALBUZZI CLAUDIA MARIA   LBZCDM64M53F205R        236.41  197.01  6.70
```

> Delimit all columns with ;, while keeping fields that contain spaces
> (for this example the name field on the second column has the name
> Claudia Maria) intact, and not dividing them into two columns

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="\t"; OFS=";" }
{
    sub(/../,"&"FS)
    $1 = $1
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk Agenti.txt
05;ALBUZZI;CLAUDIA MARIA;LBZCDM64M53F205R;236.41;197.01;6.70
```

> And finally, get all lines with agents that get a profit of more than
> 1500 (profits being displayed in the last three columns, profit is the
> sum of the three columns)

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="\t"; OFS=";" }
{
    sub(/../,"&"FS)
    $1 = $1
    profit = $(NF-2) + $(NF-1) + $NF
}
profit > 1500
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk Agenti.txt
$
```

There's no output because you only provided 1 line of sample input and it's not a line that satisfies your criteria for printing.

Answer (score 0):

> use of awk and sed

You might do all points GNU `AWK` nonetheless if your requirements stipulates usage of *both* tools then I suggest using GNU `sed` for 2 first points and GNU `AWK` for last point, let `file.tsv` content be

```
05ALBUZZI   CLAUDIA MARIA   LBZCDM64M53F205R    236.41  197.01  6.70
07ACAPULCO  GONZALEZ    LBZCDM46M35F502R    900.90  750.45  7.77
```

then

```
sed -e 'y/\t/;/' -e 's/^\(..\)/\1;/' file.tsv | awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"}$NF+$(NF-1)+$(NF-2)>1500'
```

gives output

```
07;ACAPULCO;GONZALEZ;LBZCDM46M35F502R;900.90;750.45;7.77
```

Note: for clarity I added record which should be printed. Explanation: `y` transliterate i.e. replace pairwise characters, `s` substitute 2 first characters in line with these characters (placed inside capturing group) followed by `;`, GNU `AWK` is instructed to use `;` as field separator and filter records where sum of 3 last fields is greater than 1500.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.8 and GNU Awk 5.1.0)*